# Google Drive OAuth => response=Moved Temporarily

Tags: php, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm trying to write a small PHP code that should be able to authenticate itself to a Google Account and then upload a file to its Google Drive.

This process should be done in two steps:

1. send the authentication request and get in exchange the authorization code
2. POST the authorization code and get in exchange the access token that should be used to send other requests (eq: a file upload) to the Google Drive

> Note that by using the [Google Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client) everything works smoothly.

What I want to achieve is to NOT use the Google Client Library but instead to use the simple authentication steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#overview).

By using these authentication steps mentioned earlier I send a request:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email%20profile&redirect_uri=http://example.com&response_type=code&client_id=[my-client-id]

and in exchange the redirected page should contain the "code=xxxx" parameter, like:

> http://example.com?code=xxx

where xxx is the authorization code prepended by Google to the **redirect_uri** mentioned above.

The problem is that the Google returns an error message like **Moved Temporarily** and also provides a link "The document has moved [here](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?list-of-params).". If I click that link then everything works just fine.

But I don't want the user intervention because this code works at the server level and not at the client level.

**How to solve this**? Please don't answer with "use the Google Client Library!" because I've already said that by doing so it will work but I don't want the Google Client Library dependency!

My PHP code is:

```php
$CLIENT_ID = '[the client ID from Google Developer Console]';
$CLIENT_SECRET = '[the client secret from Google Developer Console]';
$REDIRECT_URI = 'http' . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? '' : 's') . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

$ch = curl_init();

if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

    $post_fields = 'code=' . $_GET['code'] . '&client_id=' . $CLIENT_ID . '&client_secret=' . $CLIENT_SECRET . '&redirect_uri='
            . $REDIRECT_URI . '&grant_type=authorization_code';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array('Host:accounts.google.com', 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length:' . strlen($post_fields))
    );

}
else
{
    $url = sprintf('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email%%20profile&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&client_id=%s',
            $REDIRECT_URI, $CLIENT_ID
    );

}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution for this kind of problem is**:

- don't call the first request via CURL but by changing the document Location

Also change this block:

```
...
else
{
    $url = sprintf('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email%%20profile&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&client_id=%s',$REDIRECT_URI, $CLIENT_ID);
}
```

with this one:

```
...
else
{
    $url = sprintf('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email%%20profile&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&client_id=%s',$REDIRECT_URI, $CLIENT_ID);
    header('Location:'.$url);
}
```